# Can a Superset dataset use multiple data sources?

Tags: database, etl, business-intelligence, apache-superset

I'm evaluating different BI solutions and I have a specific requirement.

Our setup has multiple DS with the *same schema*, e.g. Customer1DB, Customer2DB, etc.

**Can multiple DBs be ingested in the same Superset dataset?**

Comment: SeekTable can do that, depending on the parameter it can either use another schema specifier in SQL query, or even use another connection string depending on the parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Superset does not support that.  There are a few discussions of this on the project Github, [here's one](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/7187).

Two workarounds for combining multiple DBs are:

- Do the joins in a database suited to this operation, like Trino or Drill, then use this single data source in Superset
- Someone in the thread linked above says they got this working in Superset by linking the database servers

Superset *does* support joining tables from the same database, they get combined into a new virtual dataset via Superset's SQL Lab.  And it can connect to multiple databases and use them in different charts.  It just can't join across them for a single chart.